# How to Parse json tree problems in flutter please do let me know to to handle this api respponse and handle array inside it

Tags: json, parsing, tree, flutter

http://app.webcraft.co.in/eschool/parent/parentsjson/getexams?parent_id=2&student_id=1 my API URL

my response:

```
[{
    "exam_name": "Test - April",
    "exam_result": [{
        "exam_schedule_id": "4",
        "exam_id": "2",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "Brandon",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "pre",
        "get_marks": "45.00",
        "status": "pass"
    }, {
        "exam_schedule_id": "5",
        "exam_id": "2",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "English",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "pre",
        "get_marks": "50.00",
        "status": "pass"
    }, {
        "exam_schedule_id": "6",
        "exam_id": "2",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "Hindi",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "pre",
        "get_marks": "42.00",
        "status": "pass"
    }],
    "full_mrk": 300,
    "pass_mrk": 105,
    "get_mrk": 137,
    "percentage": "45.67",
    "grade": "C"
}, {
    "exam_name": "Test - May",
    "exam_result": [{
        "exam_schedule_id": "7",
        "exam_id": "3",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "Brandon",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "pre",
        "get_marks": "45.00",
        "status": "pass"
    }, {
        "exam_schedule_id": "8",
        "exam_id": "3",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "English",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "pre",
        "get_marks": "60.00",
        "status": "pass"
    }, {
        "exam_schedule_id": "9",
        "exam_id": "3",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "Hindi",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "ABS",
        "get_marks": "0.00",
        "status": "fail"
    }],
    "full_mrk": 300,
    "pass_mrk": 105,
    "get_mrk": 105,
    "percentage": "35.00",
    "grade": "D"
}, {
    "exam_name": "Test - August",
    "exam_result": []
}, {
    "exam_name": "Final Exam",
    "exam_result": [{
        "exam_schedule_id": "25",
        "exam_id": "5",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "Brandon",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "pre",
        "get_marks": "20.00",
        "status": "fail"
    }, {
        "exam_schedule_id": "27",
        "exam_id": "5",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "English",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "pre",
        "get_marks": "40.00",
        "status": "pass"
    }, {
        "exam_schedule_id": "28",
        "exam_id": "5",
        "full_marks": "100",
        "passing_marks": "35",
        "exam_name": "Hindi",
        "exam_type": "Theory",
        "attendence": "pre",
        "get_marks": "40.00",
        "status": "pass"
    }],
    "full_mrk": 300,
    "pass_mrk": 105,
    "get_mrk": 100,
    "percentage": "33.33",
    "grade": "D"
}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting response in string format, you would first need to convert it to object format using "dart:convert",
eg

```
dynamic responseObject = new JsonEncoder().convert(responseString);
```

This should give you List or Map based on your response structure. Which you can traverse using keys like map["exam_name"] or using forEach statements.

Comment: Actually, I m very new to flutter programing please can you give full code over here how to access exam result items